# How to check the customer first time ordering in the website in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to show the dropdown on the order success page if the user is first time ordering in the website..
I am following this way but its not working for me

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function getFirstOrder($emailId){
        $emailId = 'testtest@testtests.com';

        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',array('eq'=>$emailId))->getFirstItem();

        if($order->getCustomerEmail()){
            echo 'second time order';
        }
        else{
            echo 'first time order';
        }

    }
```

How can i achieve  this.

thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this by using the following event observer after the order is placed you can show this detail in the order success page , please follow the code below

events.xml file inside the modules -> etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="test_checkout_submit_all_after"
                  instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckIfCustomerPlacingOrderForFirstTime"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer file inside the module in this path = vendor/module/Observer/CheckIfCustomerPlacingOrderForFirstTime

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as OrderCollection;

class CheckIfCustomerPlacingOrderForFirstTime implements ObserverInterface
{

    public $orderCollection;

    public function __construct(OrderCollection $orderCollection)
    {
        $this->orderCollection = $orderCollection;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $emailId = $observer->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
        $orderCollection = $this->orderCollection->create();
        $orderCollection = $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $emailId);
        if (count($orderCollection)) {
            $result = "Customer has already placed the order";
            echo $result;
        }
        if (!count($orderCollection)) {
            $result = "Fist time customer placing the order";
            echo $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this helped you by giving a like as this helps me answer more questions.Have a nice day,thanks!